# Write down a homogeneous linear system of three distinct equations in three variables that has the non-trivial solution $(x, y,z) = (1,2, 4)$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, homogeneous-equation

Write down a homogeneous linear system of three distinct equations in three variables
that has the non-trivial solution $(x, y, z) = (1,2, 4)$.

I am confused on how to approach this problem

Comment: You just need to write three equations with constant term $0$ each of which satisfy $(x,y,z)=(1,2,4)$.

For starters, one of them could be $2x+y-z=0$.

Comment: If they were scalar multiples of each other, would that be a valid answer?

Comment: You should define what a valid sequence is in your question itself. Refer [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Homogeneous_systems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y=2x;\quad z=2y;\quad z=4x.$$

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of the question is a little unclear. If we are allowed to use constants in the equations then we trivially can write the equations
$$x-1=0,\hspace{10mm}y-2=0,\hspace{10mm}z-4=0$$
to which $(x,y,z)=(1,2,4)$ is clearly the unique solution.

If we are not allowed to use constants, then there exists no homogeneous system of $3$ variables which has $(x,y,z)=(1,2,3)$ as the unique solution. This is because the form of the equations would be
$$ax+by+cz=0$$
$$dx+ey+fz=0$$
$$gx+hy+iz=0$$
which already has the trivial solution $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ so the solution $(x,y,z)=(1,2,4)$ could not be unique. If this is what the question intends, then it doesn't have a solution.

Comment: The OP didn't say that $(1,2,4)$ should be the only solution. Maybe he meant it is one of the solutions.

Comment: @ArpanBanerjee I agree that it's not clear, but that possibility seems a little silly because then the equation might as well be $$0x+0y+0z=0$$

Comment: You're right. OP should define a valid system of equations.

Comment: Homogenous system meaning the right hand side must be zero, non trivial meaning that there are some non-zero variables.

Comment: @sartar Then you might as well just use the equations that Gerry Myerson uses. The point is that $(1,2,4)$ can never be the unique solution.